# What is this error trying to run new Foundation for apps

Tags: node.js, npm, zurb-foundation, command-line-interface

Managed to install via the bower command (bower install foundation-apps)

Appears to have worked successfully because I get this:

```
bower foundation-apps#*     not-cached git://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps.git#*
bower foundation-apps#*        resolve git://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps.git#*
bower foundation-apps#*       download https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/archive/v1.0.0.tar.gz
bower foundation-apps#*        extract archive.tar.gz
bower foundation-apps#*       resolved git://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps.git#1.0.0
bower viewport-units-buggyfill#~0.4.1       not-cached git://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill.git#~0.4.1
bower viewport-units-buggyfill#~0.4.1          resolve git://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill.git#~0.4.1
bower ui-router#~0.2.12                     not-cached git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.git#~0.2.12
bower ui-router#~0.2.12                        resolve git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.git#~0.2.12
bower fastclick#~1.0.3                      not-cached git://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick.git#~1.0.3
bower fastclick#~1.0.3                         resolve git://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick.git#~1.0.3
bower tether#~0.6.5                         not-cached git://github.com/HubSpot/tether.git#~0.6.5
bower tether#~0.6.5                            resolve git://github.com/HubSpot/tether.git#~0.6.5
bower angular#~1.3.4                        not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.3.4
bower angular#~1.3.4                           resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.3.4
bower viewport-units-buggyfill#~0.4.1         download https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill/archive/v0.4.1.tar.gz
bower tether#~0.6.5                           download https://github.com/HubSpot/tether/archive/v0.6.5.tar.gz
bower fastclick#~1.0.3                        download https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/archive/v1.0.3.tar.gz
bower ui-router#~0.2.12                       download https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/archive/0.2.13.tar.gz
bower angular-animate#~1.3.4                not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#~1.3.4
bower angular-animate#~1.3.4                   resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#~1.3.4
bower jsdiff#~1.0.8                         not-cached git://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff.git#~1.0.8
bower jsdiff#~1.0.8                            resolve git://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff.git#~1.0.8
bower marked#~0.3.2                         not-cached git://github.com/chjj/marked.git#~0.3.2
bower marked#~0.3.2                            resolve git://github.com/chjj/marked.git#~0.3.2
bower allmighty-autocomplete#*              not-cached git://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete.git#*
bower allmighty-autocomplete#*                 resolve git://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete.git#*
bower angular-mocks#~1.3.4                  not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#~1.3.4
bower angular-mocks#~1.3.4                     resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#~1.3.4
bower angular#~1.3.4                          download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/archive/v1.3.5.tar.gz
bower marked#~0.3.2                           download https://github.com/chjj/marked/archive/v0.3.2.tar.gz
bower allmighty-autocomplete#*                checkout master
bower jsdiff#~1.0.8                           download https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff/archive/v1.0.8.tar.gz
bower angular-animate#~1.3.4                  download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate/archive/v1.3.5.tar.gz
bower fastclick#~1.0.3                         extract archive.tar.gz
bower tether#~0.6.5                            extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-mocks#~1.3.4                    download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks/archive/v1.3.5.tar.gz
bower allmighty-autocomplete#*                resolved git://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete.git#3854e81f53
bower fastclick#~1.0.3                        resolved git://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick.git#1.0.3
bower tether#~0.6.5                           resolved git://github.com/HubSpot/tether.git#0.6.5
bower viewport-units-buggyfill#~0.4.1          extract archive.tar.gz
bower jsdiff#~1.0.8                            extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-animate#~1.3.4                   extract archive.tar.gz
bower marked#~0.3.2                            extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-animate#~1.3.4                  resolved git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.3.5
bower angular-mocks#~1.3.4                     extract archive.tar.gz
bower jsdiff#~1.0.8                       invalid-meta jsdiff is missing "main" entry in bower.json
bower jsdiff#~1.0.8                       invalid-meta jsdiff is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
bower jsdiff#~1.0.8                           resolved git://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff.git#1.0.8
bower angular-mocks#~1.3.4                    resolved git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.3.5
bower viewport-units-buggyfill#~0.4.1         resolved git://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill.git#0.4.1
bower marked#~0.3.2                       invalid-meta marked is missing "main" entry in bower.json
bower marked#~0.3.2                       invalid-meta marked is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
bower marked#~0.3.2                           resolved git://github.com/chjj/marked.git#0.3.2
bower ui-router#~0.2.12                        extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular#~1.3.4                           extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular#~1.3.4                          resolved git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.5
bower ui-router#~0.2.12                       resolved git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.git#0.2.13
bower foundation-apps#~1.0.0                   install foundation-apps#1.0.0
bower allmighty-autocomplete#*                 install allmighty-autocomplete#3854e81f53
bower fastclick#~1.0.3                         install fastclick#1.0.3
bower tether#~0.6.5                            install tether#0.6.5
bower angular-animate#~1.3.4                   install angular-animate#1.3.5
bower jsdiff#~1.0.8                            install jsdiff#1.0.8
bower angular-mocks#~1.3.4                     install angular-mocks#1.3.5
bower viewport-units-buggyfill#~0.4.1          install viewport-units-buggyfill#0.4.1
bower marked#~0.3.2                            install marked#0.3.2
bower angular#~1.3.4                           install angular#1.3.5
bower ui-router#~0.2.12                        install ui-router#0.2.13

foundation-apps#1.0.0 bower_components/foundation-apps
├── allmighty-autocomplete#3854e81f53
├── angular#1.3.5
├── angular-animate#1.3.5
├── angular-mocks#1.3.5
├── fastclick#1.0.3
├── jsdiff#1.0.8
├── marked#0.3.2
├── tether#0.6.5
├── ui-router#0.2.13
└── viewport-units-buggyfill#0.4.1

allmighty-autocomplete#3854e81f53 bower_components/allmighty-autocomplete

fastclick#1.0.3 bower_components/fastclick

tether#0.6.5 bower_components/tether

angular-animate#1.3.5 bower_components/angular-animate
└── angular#1.3.5

jsdiff#1.0.8 bower_components/jsdiff

angular-mocks#1.3.5 bower_components/angular-mocks
└── angular#1.3.5

viewport-units-buggyfill#0.4.1 bower_components/viewport-units-buggyfill

marked#0.3.2 bower_components/marked

angular#1.3.5 bower_components/angular

ui-router#0.2.13 bower_components/ui-router
└── angular#1.3.5
```

But when I try foundation-apps new myApp, I get this:

-bash: foundation-apps: command not found

So... I take it it's not installed? Just having a hard time figuring this out.

Comment: did you install command-line interface?
`npm install -g foundation-cli`

Comment: I get this as well would be good to find a solution